# How to clear only one floated object?

Tags: css, css-float

A question about floats and clearing. [Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rlesko/KdMmP/)
How do I get the text to appear under the red object?
If I use `clear: left`, the text appears under the black object because it has greater height than the red one.
Is it possible to get that look I'm looking for by using only float and clear?

Comment: I just played a bit more and found out that you can do this by wrapping the red object and text in their separate div so you get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rlesko/KdMmP/1/).

Funny how you get to the answer yourself immediately after asking the question. :D

Can't add it as the answer so here's a comment.

Comment: I was just in the process of saying that you can achieve it by wrapping them both in a floated `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `red` div followed by the `h2` tag in a containing div that floats left (you can remove the float:left from the `red` div. and you can remove the `clear:left` from `h2` :)

http://jsfiddle.net/XqLFX/

Comment: Yeah, I got it myself almost instantly after asking the question, thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong on wrong design. This is the new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2f2s9/1/)

```
<div id="blue">
    <div id="black"></div>
    <div id="new">      
        <div id="red"></div>
         <h2>TEXT</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Make the new div float left

```
#new{width:200px;float:left}
```

Comment: Thanks, but  there is no need for `red` and `h2` to `float:left` and `clear:left` respectively.